# Wrong object is being deleted from array

Tags: java

My program is not having any errors, but the wrong student is being deleted from my course (an array) and I'm not sure why. If I change the name to the 3rd student (James), I get an NPE error on the dropStudent lines. I think it might have something to do with my dropStudent method, but I think it should loop through course with index equal to 'i' and when that index equals the name, it becomes null leaving the other 2 students.

I'll post the code below along with my output.

```
package reviseCourse;
import java.util.*;

public class ReviseCourse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create new course to enroll students in
        ReviseCourse cs216 = new ReviseCourse("cs216");

        // Add 3 students to the course
        cs216.addStudent("William");
        cs216.addStudent("Angela");
        cs216.addStudent("James");

        // Drop the student William from the course
        cs216.dropStudent("William");

        // Print course name and students individually by looping through the numberOfStudents
        System.out.println("The students in the course " + cs216.getCourseName() + " are:");
        for (int i = 0; i < cs216.getNumberOfStudents(); i++) {
            System.out.print(students[i] + " ");
        }

    }

    private String courseName;
    private static String[] students = new String[100];
    private String[] course = new String[students.length + 1];
    private int numberOfStudents;

    public void populateCourse() {
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            course[i] = students[i];
            System.out.println(course[i]);
        }
    }

    public ReviseCourse(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public void addStudent(String student) {
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            course[i] = students[i];
        }
        students[numberOfStudents] = student;
        numberOfStudents++;
    }

    public String[] getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public int getNumberOfStudents() {
        return numberOfStudents;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void dropStudent(String student) {
        for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {
            if (course[i].equals("William")) {
                course[i] = null;
                numberOfStudents--;
                break;
            }
        }       
    }

    // Deletes all students from the course
    public void clear() {
        numberOfStudents = 0;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
The students in the course cs216 are:
William Angela
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropStudent` modifies the `course` array, but not the `student` array, which you're printing from. The bigger issue is that you're just assigning `null` to the student you want to delete, but decrementing the number of students, so even if you print from `courses` you won't get the right output.

If the array of students is:

```
William | Angela | James : numStudents = 3
```

Then dropping William makes the array:

```
null | Angela | James : numStudents = 2
```

Now if you try to print the students, your code will will print the first two elements, which are `null` and Angela. Probably not what you want.

You should either be shifting over elements when you drop students, so that the array would instead look like:

```
Angela | James | null : numStudents = 2
```

After dropping William, or instead of reinventing the wheel just use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `dropStudent` method:

```
    if (course[i].equals("William")) {
```

So this method is only ever going to drop William, no matter which student is actually passed into it.

Additionally, you are looping through the `students` array, but `dropStudent` only removes students from the `course` array.

Comment: Yeah but in the output you can see he's still there, but James stays.

Comment: James is still in the`student` array.  You just don't see him in that loop because you're only looping up to `numberOfStudents`, which has decreased by one.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void dropStudent(String student) {
    for (int i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {
        if (course[i].equals(student) {
            course[i] = null;
            numberOfStudents--;
            //can re order to keep the array tidy, ie go with for if you find a 
            //null then set it to be the next value in the array; thus will keep 
           //array management more efficient
            break;
        }
    }       
}
```